# Add typings for prototyped function

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a JavaScript `function` in Node module like this (simplified):

`index.js`:

```
var BadRequestError = require('./error')

Guard.prototype = {

  /**
   *
   * @param {String} property
   * @return {_middleware}
   */
  check: function (property) {
    const _middleware = function _middleware (req, res, next) {
      const ok = property === 'ping'
      next(!ok ? new BadRequestError('doing_it_wrong', { message: `you're doing it wrong`}) : null)
    }

    return _middleware
  }
}

module.exports = function (options) {
  return new Guard(options)
}
```

`error.js`:

```
module.exports = function BadRequestError (code, error) {
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)

  this.name = this.constructor.name
  this.message = error.message

  this.code = code
  this.status = 400
  this.inner = error
}

util.inherits(module.exports, Error)
```

The usage is as follows:

`test.js`:

```
var guard = require('../index')({
  someProperty: 'test',
})
var req = {}
guard.check('ping')(req, res, function (err) {
  assert.deepStrictEqual(null, err)
})
```

I tried to create TypeScript typings for it using several approaches but none seems to work:

`index.d.ts`:

```
export declare interface IGuardOptions {
    property: string
}
```

exporting via `class` declaration:

```
export declare class Guard  {
    constructor(options: IGuardOptions)
    check(required: string | Array<string>): any
}
```

exporting via `interface` declaration:

```
export declare interface Guard {
    check(property: string): any
}
export declare type GuardConstructor = new(options: IGuardOptions) => Guard
```

Comment: Your issue could possibly be related to the fact that you are overwriting the `Guard` "factory" export with `BadRequestError` which is a completely different type.

Comment: BadRequestError is a different file

Comment: That's somewhat confusing, can you remove it if it is not relevant to your question? Where are you implementing the type declarations? Also in a separate file?

Comment: Sorry, should be better now. The `BadRequestError` might be return in the `middleware`

Comment: Where is the `Guard` class declared? Is that also a separate file?

Comment: `interface` and `class` were two different approaches I tried, but all of them have been in `index.d.ts`

Comment: Why are your modules written in Javascript if you want to use Typescript? Are you attempting to use these types in a different project? Or are you willing to convert them to Typescript?

Comment: They might be written in TypeScript eventually but for now just Typings should be created and the current implementation should remain in plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "not working" since you are not writing any Typescript code, just declarations, so I will assume that `test.js` should be `test.ts` to answer your question.

You'll want to create a type declaration along side the original Javascript source (like you have already done), but you need to make sure that the structure is equivalent to the original module. Your Typescript declarations indicate that there are multiple exports while the Javascript implementations only have a single export.

error.d.ts

```
declare class BadRequestError extends Error {
    code: string;
    status: number;
    inner: Error;

    constructor(code: string, error: Error);
}

export = BadRequestError;
```

index.d.ts

```
import {Handler} from 'express';

declare interface GuardOptions {
    someProperty: string;
}

declare class Guard {
    constructor(options: GuardOptions);

    check(property: string): Handler;
}

declare function guardFactory(options: GuardOptions): Guard;

export = guardFactory;
```

test.ts

```
import {Request, Response} from 'express';

import guardFactory = require('./index');

const guard = guardFactory({
    someProperty: 'test',
});

const middleware = guard.check('ping');

const req = {} as Request;
const res = {} as Response;
const next = function (err) {
    assert.deepStrictEqual(null, err);
};

middleware(req, res, next);
```

Comment: "not working" did mean neither WebStorm nor VS Code did provide Code completion, Syntax highlighting or validation for the typings. Thanks for your patience.